# Remote Powershell session connection failure with Kerberos authentication

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an on-premises network and an Azure virtual network that are connected together via a gateway.

[image: infrastructure_diagram]

With this setup, all machines (on-premises and Azure) are joined to the domain which allows me remote access to the administrative shares as well as remote Powershell sessions on each machine in the Azure virtual network from machines in my office.  For example, I can simply open up Windows Explorer and type in the address bar `\\machinename\c$` or I can open a remote Powershell session by using the command `$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName machinename`.

This works perfectly for one of my Azure subscriptions, but on another Azure subscription that appears to be configured identically, the remote Powershell command is failing with error:

> New-PSSession : [machinename] Connecting to remote server machinename failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while 
>   using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer machinename. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, 
>   see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

When I look in DNS on the Azure domain controller, the machine that I am trying to connect to exists.  When I look in DNS on-premises, the machine is missing.  What it looks like to me is a replication problem between the two domain controllers.

The first thing that is likely to be suggested is to start looking at WinRM configurations on the client machine.  To be clear, the same machine is able to connect successfully to machines in a virtual network in a different Azure subscription so it is very unlikely that anything on the client machine needs to be changed.  Nevertheless, I Googled the Kerberos error with remote Powershell and have checked that the `TrustedHosts` setting on the client is set to `*`.

Interestingly enough, I can successfully open a remote Powershell session from a machine in the Azure subscription to a machine in my office, I just can't go the other direction....from Azure to my office.  This would seem to indicate maybe a one-way trust instead of two-way, but I am not sure how to verify this.

I ran [the tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30005) and it is reporting that everything is working with regard to replication.

So I guess what I am wondering is if this is truly a replication issue or if someone can give me an idea of what the problem might really be.

**Edit 1**

Now it looks like the domain controller in the Azure network is replicating just fine but any other VM that I add to the Azure network is not replicating.  Based on this I will guess that the replication is working, but it would seem it only works for the domain controller and not any other machine.  I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Please render an image from the diagram and upload that to the question instead of linking to OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems that the DNS records on Azure domain controller are not  replicated to the on-premises domain controller.

To verify this, you can run the command below on the on-premises machine, and use the **IP address** as the value of parameter -ComputerName instead of the machine name. The PowerShell session should be established successfully if this is a DNS issue.

New-PSSession -ComputerName IP address of server on Azure

Also, you can run the following commands on the domain controllers to check the replication status.

```
repadmin /kcc
repadmin /replisummlry
```

If the output of commands are successfully, you can run the following command to replicate manually, and check the DNS again.

```
repadmin /syncall
```

Finally, to check the trust relationship, you can refer to the following link for step-by-step guide.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753821(v=ws.11).aspx

**Update**

Based on the new information you provided, I would recommend to check the type of DNS zone on the Azure DNS server. Please make sure the type is Primary zone, and store the zone in Active Directory.

You can check this by using the DNS Manager.

[image]

Comment: repadmin /kcc reports "Consistency check on localhost successful".  repadmin /replsum reports no failures for source DSA or destination DSA.  repadmin /syncall finishes and reports no errors.  I've updated the original post with another interesting piece of information.

Comment: Using IP address with remote powershell session and specific credentials does work, but I don't want to have to use specific credentials.

Comment: As a workaround, you can add DNS A records for Azure VMs on the on-premise DNS server. Besides, according to the new information you provided, I've update the original post for checking the DNS zone type.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thak you for the assistance.  We ended up scrapping the entire Azure subscription and starting from scratch.  Not sure what went wrong the first time we did this, but the new subscription is working as expected.